# Disable ArcMap Add-In button Depending on Layout View Or Data View

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, button, disabled-control, arcmap

VS2010, ArcMap, ArcObjects, C#

I have created an ArcMap Add-In that has one button on it. I am having trouble making this button enabled or disabled depending on which view you are in (Either Layout view or Data View). I already have a a function that tells the user which view they are in. It displays a little popup box that says you're either in Layout view or Data view depending.

I am sure I can manipulate my function to fit my overall need. I'm just not sure of:

1. The ArcObject or C# "special function / interface" I'd need to use
2. Where to put a function that disables/enables a button at. Would it go in the form.cs code?